# Is it possible to access qemu monitor when VM is already running?

Tags: qemu

I have a `qemu` VM running in daemonized mode:

```
qemu --enable-kvm -daemonize -m 512M -device e1000,netdev=network,mac=52:54:00:12:34:58 -netdev tap,id=network,ifname=tap301,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=10G_HDD_clone2 -display vnc=:11
```

Is it somehow possible to access `qemu` [monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor) now when the VM is already running without shutting down the VM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like it's running a VNC server at display :11 (on the host system), which you should be able to connect a VNC client to. E.g.,

```
xvnc4viewer :11
```

There are of course many other VNC viewers to choose from, and I would believe any of them will do.

See http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html for more details.

EDIT: the page I point at suggests `-vnc :11` rather than your `-display vnc=:11`, so now I'm not sure. But Gentoo's `qemu` documentation at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options suggests the format `-display vnc :11` (without equal sign) so maybe yours works too, on your platform.